# What is the meaning of 'efibootmgr -v' after EFI file path

Tags: boot, windows, dual-boot, uefi

When I run `efibootmgr` to list all my boot options, this is the output:

```
$ efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0002,0003,0001
Boot0000* (my linux distro grub boot)
Boot0001* file
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0003* (my linux distro systemd-boot)
```

And when I want to see more detailed output, I get this:

```
$ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0002,0003,0001
Boot0000* (my linux distro grub boot)       HD(1,GPT,3e1eXXXX-f3XX-40XX-b1XX-569aXXXXXXXX,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\DISTRONAME-GRUB\GRUBX64.EFI)
Boot0001* file  VenHw(99e2XXXX-75XX-4bXX-a2XX-c538XXXXXXXX)
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,3e1eXXXX-f3XX-40XX-b1XX-569aXXXXXXXX,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.X.X.X.X.-.5.c.X.X.-.4.e.X.X.-.a.c.X.X.-.f.3.2.b.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.}....................
Boot0003* (my linux distro systemd-boot)    HD(1,GPT,3e1eXXXX-f3XX-40XX-b1XX-569aXXXX,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\DISTRONAME-SYSTEMDBOOT\systemd-bootx64.efi)
```

Based on my reasoning and quick search in man pages (https://linux.die.net/man/8/efibootmgr), the format of the output is:

```
BootNNNNA NAME WHATTOBOOT
```

where:

```
NNNN = boot number (0000 until maybe 9999)
A = * if active, no asterisk if not active
NAME = string label that will be shown on vendor/motherboard BIOS (UEFI)
WHATTOBOOT = can be
  - HD({NUMBER},{GPT/MBR},{UUID-from-blkid-PARTUUID})/File({\PATH\TO\EFI})
  - PXE ((I have no such boot option in this PC))
```

Now what I'm curious is about the meaning of `efibootmgr -v` output for `Windows boot manager` that shows as:

```
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,3e1eXXXX-f3XX-40XX-b1XX-569aXXXXXXXX,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.X.X.X.X.-.5.c.X.X.-.4.e.X.X.-.a.c.X.X.-.f.3.2.b.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.}....................
```

- Based on it's PARTUUID, it's located on my EFI partition (same with my other boot options)
- Then it's EFI file is at \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
- Then lastly, there's a string (or maybe binary) following:

  ```
  WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.X.X.X.X.-.5.c.X.X.-.4.e.X.X.-.a.c.X.X.-.f.3.2.b.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.}....................
  ```

What I'm asking is: what does this string mean? It seems like UUID if I remove all dot (.) characters between (which will make it into `xBCOBJECT=9deaXXXX-5cXX-4eXX-acXX-f32bXXXXXXXX`

I'm also curious about what is the second boot option mean: `Boot0001* file` or the verbose version `Boot0001* file  VenHw(99e2XXXX-75XX-4bXX-a2XX-c538XXXXXXXX)`

- I suspect it's a boot from flash drive / thumb drive that I forgot to delete a few years ago, is this correct? Or is it something else?

Additional information:

Version:

```
$ efibootmgr --version
version 17
```

My setup: Windows+linux dual boot, on linux I installed these boot managers: grub and systemd-boot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

> Binary data buffer that is passed to the loaded image.

**Longer description of search process**

[efibootmgr source](https://github.com/rhboot/efibootmgr) contains a function which outputs EFI boot variables (file efibootmgr.c):

```c
  static void
  show_vars(const char *prefix)
  {
          list_t *pos;
          var_entry_t *boot;
          const unsigned char *description;
          efi_load_option *load_option;

          list_for_each(pos, &entry_list) {
                  boot = list_entry(pos, var_entry_t, list);
                  load_option = (efi_load_option *)boot->data;
                  description = efi_loadopt_desc(load_option, boot->data_size);
                  if (boot->name)
                          printf("%s", boot->name);
                  else
                          printf("%s%04X", prefix, boot->num);

                  printf("%c ", (efi_loadopt_attrs(load_option)
                          ⁞      & LOAD_OPTION_ACTIVE) ? '*' : ' ');
                  printf("%s", description);

                  show_var_path(load_option, boot->data_size);

                  fflush(stdout);
          }
  }
```

Of interest is the line

```c
description = efi_loadopt_desc(load_option, boot->data_size);
```

So, we need to find a function `efi_loadopt_desc`. It is not contained in efibootmgr itself. A search of include files in /usr/include gives:

```
$ grep -ri efi_loadopt_desc /usr/include
/usr/include/efivar/efiboot-loadopt.h:extern const unsigned char * efi_loadopt_desc(efi_load_option *opt,
```

If we look inside the file /usr/include/efivar/efiboot-loadopt.h states:

```c
/*
 * libefiboot - library for the manipulation of EFI boot variables
 * Copyright 2012-2015 Red Hat, Inc.
 * Copyright (C) 2001 Dell Computer Corporation <Matt_Domsch@dell.com>
 *
 ...
 */
```

Further investigation leads to the [efivar repository](https://github.com/rhboot/efivar), which contains the function `efi_loadopt_desc` inside the file src/loadopt.c. There it simply returns `opt->description` field of a `struct efi_load_option_s`:

```c
last_desc = ucs2_to_utf8(opt->description, limit);
```

That struct is defined as

```c
typedef struct efi_load_option_s {
        uint32_t attributes;
        uint16_t file_path_list_length;
        uint16_t description[];
        // uint8_t file_path_list[];
        // uint8_t optional_data[];
} PACKED efi_load_option;
```

So, the part which gets output after the load option file path is called "optional data". Further investigation leads to the file `src/efivarfs.c` and the function `efivarfs_get_variable`, which shows that it reads the efivarfs (EFI var file system), which usually is located under /sys/firmware/efi/efivarfs, and exposes a number of virtual "files". Files with names beginning with `Boot000` contain information about boot options, among other data, this "optional data" describing a particular boot entry. It seems the "optional data" is only loaded if the combined information from boot name, boot entry file path and "optional data" doesn't exceed `opt_size`.

Further information:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Services

> **Variable services**
> UEFI variables provide a way to store data, in particular non-volatile data. Some UEFI variables are shared between platform firmware and operating systems. Variable namespaces are identified by GUIDs, and variables are key/value pairs. For example, UEFI variables can be used to keep crash messages in NVRAM after a crash for the operating system to retrieve after a reboot.[45]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#UEFI_booting

> The boot configuration is defined by variables stored in NVRAM, including variables that indicate the file system paths to OS loaders or OS kernels.

**Note:** UEFI specification has this to say about "optional data":

https://uefi.org/specifications
https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_8_final.pdf
(page 72)

> **OptionalData**
> The remaining bytes in the load option descriptor are a binary data
> buffer that is passed to the loaded image. If the field is zero bytes
> long, a NULL pointer is passed to the loaded image. The number of
> bytes in OptionalData can be computed by subtracting the
> starting offset of OptionalData from total size in bytes of the
> EFI_LOAD_OPTION.